# Passing parameter from the current URL to redirect to another url

Tags: php, links, variables

I have a search results page and on the page, I would like to be able to filter by category. So when the user searches an item, it gets passed to the results page in the url like:

website.com/?s=example

What I would like to do is take the value of "s" and use it in a link to another page.

What I am thinking is doing something like this:

`$_searchquery = $_GET['s'];`

Then adding the $_searchquery variable to the url I am wanting to redirect to by doing something along these lines:

`<a href="website.com/?s=<?php echo $_searchquery ?>&category_name=example">
 Example Category </a>`

Which in theory will redirect to a search results page that will display the search results for 'example' that appear in the 'example' category. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me! The goal was to get a button that would filter my search results by post category and the above solution works exactly how I wanted it to.